# SpriteKit Hexagonal map:Tiles Detection when player node move on

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I ask this question because i didn't found any solution for this kind of issues. In fact Hex map support are not very popular.

I'am making a game with the SpriteKit Framework.
I use SktileMapNode with an Hexagonal map,  with 1 set of 4 groups tiles.

The playernode  moves on each tiles, what i wan't it's when he move on a specifics tiles some event can be triggered ( print , function , Sktransition) but for the moment i'm stuck on just detecting those tiles.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQYSR.png)

I setup the user data ( as bool ) and apply them in the code , but nothing happened, even with a touch event on a tile.

this is the code in the GameScene :

```
  func handleTapFrom(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state != .ended {
        return
    }

    let recognizorLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view!)
    let location = self.convertPoint(fromView: recognizorLocation)



    let column = galaxieMapnode.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: location)
    let row = galaxieMapnode.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: location)
    if let tile = galaxieMapnode.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row) {

    let data = tile.userData?.value(forKey: "wormholeTile") as? Bool

    if (data == true) {

        print("wormhole touched")


    }


    }

}
```

the code in another extension file for the player at the touchdown :

```
func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {




    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTapFrom(recognizer:)))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    view?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    let position = thePlayer.position

    let column = galaxieMapnode.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: position)
    let row = galaxieMapnode.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: position)


    if let tile:SKTileDefinition = galaxieMapnode.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row) {


        if  let tileBoolData = tile.userData?["wormholeTile"] as? Bool {

            if (tileBoolData == true) {

                print("Wormhole touched")


            }



        }




    } else {


        print("different tile")


    }



    }
```

Maybe i use the bad gestureRecogniser or i place those code in the bad scope.

any help are welcome.

thank you

[image for description of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQYSR.png)

EDIT  :

@KnightOfDragon

ok i erase all the gesture recog, and the code in my move function :

```
extension GameScene  {



func move(theXAmount:CGFloat , theYAmount:CGFloat, theAnimation:String )  {


    let wait:SKAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.05)

    let walkAnimation:SKAction = SKAction(named: theAnimation, duration: moveSpeed )!

    let moveAction:SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: theXAmount, y: theYAmount, duration: moveSpeed )

    let group:SKAction = SKAction.group( [ walkAnimation, moveAction ] )

    let finish:SKAction = SKAction.run {



        let position = self.thePlayer.position

        let column = self.galaxieMapnode.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: position)
        let row = self.galaxieMapnode.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: position)


        if let tile:SKTileDefinition = self.galaxieMapnode.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row) {


            if  let tileBoolData = tile.userData?["wormholeTile"] as? Bool {

                if (tileBoolData == true) {

                    print("Wormhole touched")


                }



            }




        } else {


            print("different tile")


        }


    }
```

but the output is only "different tile " when the move end.
thanks for the note anyway.

any idea maybe ?

Comment: You shouldnt be using tap gesture the way you are doing it, every time you tap down, you are creating a new gesture.  I would avoid it all together since you have to convert from view coordinate to scene coordinates

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I remove the gesture and apply the code in the end of the SkAction move of the Player node. The console only print "the different tile " output. Any idea why ? Even on the tile I need the feedback

Comment: i edit the original post for clarity